# Removing stripes on 2D NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a 2D NumPy array and a 2D mask (boolean) with the same dimension. The mask has stripes of *False* along its *x* or *y* axes. What is the best way to extract the elements in the array only where the mask is *True*, and maintain its dimension according to the mask, i.e. the result is also a 2D array?

Image of 2D mask with stripes of False:

[image: 2D mask with stripes of False]

Comment: I fear it won't be possible to extract a 2D array from this (or at least with numpy), because without the mask's elements the output is no longer a square matrix... You could achieve it with lists though, or simply by keeping the mask on your array.

Comment: What is the expected value in the new (extracted) array where the mask array value is `False`? eg, what value should be at `[0,0]` and `[160,160]`?